# webrtc: Steps to upgrade/downgrade call

Tags: android, webrtc

I am developing android audio/video call client using webrtc. The client supports upgrade from audio-only call to audio-video call and vice-versa (downgrade).
I have implemented the functionality and would like to confirm if I am following the correct path to do this. Below are the steps I am following. Can someone please verify if they are correct?

1. Upgrade from audio-only call to audio-video call.

   - A (offer) calls B(answer) to setup audio-only call.
   - A initiates upgrade. Stops the video source.
   - A removes previous media stream from PeerConnection.
   - A removes audiotrack from mediastream.
   - A adds audio track.
   - A initializes video constraints.
   - A adds mandatory sdp constraints  ("OfferToReceiveVideo", "true"). Previously this was set to false.
   - A enables the video.
   - Adds video track to media stream
   - Starts the video source.
   - A(offer) sends new sdp to B(answer) on ice gathering is complete.
   - B gets the sdp as offer.
   - B follows the same steps as above before generating the answer.
2. Downgrade to audio-only call from audio-video call.

   - A (offer) calls B(answer) to setup audio-video call.
   - A initiates downgrade. Stops the video source.
   - A removes previous media stream from PeerConnection.
   - A removes audiotrack from mediastream.
   - A adds audio track.
   - A adds mandatory sdp constraints  ("OfferToReceiveVideo", "false"). Previously this was set to true.
   - A(offer) sends new sdp to B(answer) on ice gathering is complete.
   - B gets the sdp as offer.
   - B follows the same steps as above before generating the answer.

Do let me if I am missing something or doing something unnecessary!

Comment: Questions on WebRTC are usually answered much faster on the discuss-webrtc Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/discuss-webrtc

Comment: Before asking here, I already asked the question there: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!starred/discuss-webrtc/WAvny-lEzo8
but no response from there as well.